# Spock - running data table count

Tags: groovy, spock

Is there any method in Spock to transparently get the current running count when using data tables without the the need to have it as an explicit input parameter?

For example

```
class MathSpec extends Specification {
    def "maximum of two numbers"(int a, int b, int c) {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c
        println "this is row:" + $currentRowCount//??


        where:
        a | b | c
        1 | 3 | 3
        7 | 4 | 4
        0 | 0 | 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really ugly because `iterationCount` is a private variable, but possible:

**Example spec:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class PieceTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll
  def "do something with data table item #item"() {
    expect:
    println specificationContext
      .currentIteration
      .parent
      .iterationNameProvider
      .iterationCount

    where:
    item  | anotherItem
    "foo" | 333
    "bar" | 444
    "zot" | 555
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
1
2
3
```

Please note that this only works for `@Unroll`ed feature methods, not without that annotation.

---

**Update: Expose iteration count via global Spock extension**

*Disclaimer: I love Spock but I am not fluent in Groovy meta programming. This is also my first Spock extension.*

You may know [built-in Spock extensions](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/extensions.html) which are mostly annotation-driven, such as `@Ignore`, `@Timeout`, `@Stepwise`, `@Issue`, `@AutoCleanup`. But there are also global extensions which are not described in the manual but still exist, e.g. `ReportLogExtension`, `IncludeExcludeExtension`.

Unfortunately the manual does not describe how to create such extensions, but with some googling and source code research you can find out. It is nothing for beginners, though.

**Global Spock extension:**

This extension adds a dynamic member `iterationCount` to each Spock specification.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app

import org.spockframework.runtime.AbstractRunListener
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractGlobalExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureInfo
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.IterationInfo
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo

class IterationCountExtension extends AbstractGlobalExtension {
  @Override
  void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
    spec.addListener(new IterationCountListener())
  }

  static class IterationCountListener extends AbstractRunListener {
    MetaClass metaClass
    int iterationCount

    @Override
    void beforeSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
      println spec.name
      metaClass = spec.reflection.metaClass
    }

    @Override
    void beforeFeature(FeatureInfo feature) {
      println "  " + feature.name
      iterationCount = 0
      metaClass.iterationCount = iterationCount
    }

    @Override
    void beforeIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {
      println "    " + iteration.name
      metaClass.iterationCount = iterationCount++
    }
  }
}
```

Each extension needs to be registered. So please also add a file `META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension` with the following content to your test resources:

```
de.scrum_master.app.IterationCountExtension
```

**Showcase specification:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class SampleTest extends Specification {
  def "no data table"() {
    expect:
    println "      " + iterationCount
  }

  def "data table items"() {
    expect:
    println "      " + iterationCount

    where:
    item  | anotherItem
    "foo" | 333
    "bar" | 444
    "zot" | 555
  }

  @Unroll
  def "unrolled data table item"() {
    expect:
    println "      " + iterationCount

    where:
    item  | anotherItem
    "foo" | 333
    "bar" | 444
    "zot" | 555
  }

  @Unroll
  def "unrolled data table item #item"() {
    expect:
    println "      " + iterationCount

    where:
    item  | anotherItem
    "foo" | 333
    "bar" | 444
    "zot" | 555
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
SampleTest
  no data table
    no data table
      0
  data table items
    data table items
      0
    data table items
      1
    data table items
      2
  unrolled data table item
    unrolled data table item[0]
      0
    unrolled data table item[1]
      1
    unrolled data table item[2]
      2
  unrolled data table item #item
    unrolled data table item foo
      0
    unrolled data table item bar
      1
    unrolled data table item zot
      2
```

As you can see, the extension works regardless of whether `@Unroll` is used or not. In this respect it is also better than the quick & dirty solution from above.

BTW, if you want the count to be 1-based instead of 0-based, just switch the expression `iterationCount++` to `++iterationCount` in the extension listener method `beforeIteration`.

Comment: Nice find!  I was digging through the source, but didn't get there ;-)  I guess another caveat is that it relies on the internals of Spock never changing, but +1 for effort ;-)

Comment: I did not go as far as reading the sources, but used a breakpoint and the good debugger in IntelliJ IDEA. Piece of cake. ;-)

Comment: I just added a solution variant utilising a global Spock extension to my answer. Check it out if you like. This one was far more fun to learn and implement than my quick & dirty solution. :))

Comment: Really nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Unroll` with `#iterationCount`, ie:

```
import spock.lang.*

class MathSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    def "maximum of #a and #b is #c (iteration #iterationCount)"() {
        given:
        def result = Math.max(a, b)

        expect:
        result == c

        where:
        a | b | c
        1 | 3 | 3
        7 | 4 | 4
        0 | 0 | 0
    }
}
```

PS:  Don't call your class `Math`, then try to call `Math.max` ;-)

Comment: Ok, but using `iterationCount` in spec's body itself is not possible?

Comment: @tim_yates - thanks but can't get access to the iterationCount in the method body which is what i need

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this answer. Verified on spock version 2.1-groovy-3.0 to get the row number use:

```
  specificationContext.currentIteration.iterationIndex
```

A